# Exception propagation in objective c

Tags: objective-c, nsexception

I am new to Objective-c and creating an custom exception. I want to handle an exception(throw in function3()) in functin1() of implementationC. Here is my code:

```
@implementatin A
 function3()
  {
    if(contion)
    throw [[ApiException alloc] initwithName:@"", reasong:@"" userInfo:nil];
  }


@implementatin B
  function2()
   {
   function3();
    }

 @implementatin C
 function1()
     {
      function2();
      }
```

Comment: What is your question **?**

Comment: `@try / @catch / @finally`

Comment: want to handle exception(throw in function3()) in functin1() of implementation C.

Comment: Exceptions aren't all that common in Obj-C. You probably shouldn't be using them.

Comment: your code is so far away from compiling. you should read a tutorial on objective-c first...

Answer (score 1):

You can propagate an exception by catching it and re-throwing it:

```
@try {
    [self doSomethingElse:anArray];
}
@catch (NSException *theException) {
    @throw;
}
```

However you need to know that Objective-C exceptions are not the same as C++ exceptions and can lead to leaks if not used with care.  Their use is probably a bad idea.  Ensure you read Apple's [Exception Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Exceptions/Tasks/HandlingExceptions.html) properly.

Answer (score 1):

Obviously you are very new to Objective-C: There are no functions, but methods. So my first recommendation is to get a book or tutorial.

Beside this: Do you know that in Objective-C exception are *not* the first choice to handle errors?
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Exceptions/Exceptions.html

One of the reasons is, that ARC does not work with exceptions out of the box. (You have to turn exception handling on, which leads to a runtime penalty.)

To your Q: Typically you create exceptions with `NSException` and throw them with `@throw`. You have the usual try-catch-finally rethrow pattern to handle them:
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Exceptions/Tasks/HandlingExceptions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000059-BBCHGJIJ

```
@try
{
   // something that can throw an exception
}
@catch (…)
{
   // catch it here
   @throw; // rethrow the catched exception.
}
```